# Symfony 5 error "The class passed to the logging system does not have a handler" monolog?

Tags: php, symfony, monolog

I encountered such a strange error, I am trying to keep logs using monolog in symfony 5-configured according to [this instruction](https://symfony.com/doc/current/logging.html)
As is usually the case with official documentation, it is absolutely not true... :(

*config/packages/prod/monolog.yaml*

```
monolog:
    handlers:
        main:
            type: stream
            path: "%kernel.logs_dir%/%kernel.environment%.log"
            level: debug
            channels: ["!event"]
        # uncomment to get logging in your browser
        # you may have to allow bigger header sizes in your Web server configuration
        #firephp:
        #    type: firephp
        #    level: info
        #chromephp:
        #    type: chromephp
        #    level: info
        console:
            type: console
            process_psr_3_messages: false
            channels: ["!event", "!doctrine", "!console"]
```

My class that tries to write messages to the log

```
class Log
{
    /**
     * @var LoggerInterface
     */
    private LoggerInterface $logger;

    /**
     * Log constructor.
     * @param LoggerInterface $app_logger
     */
    public function __construct(LoggerInterface $app_logger)
    {
        $this->logger = $app_logger;
    }

    public function write()
    {
         $this->logger->error('hello monolog');
    }
```

But I get the error:

> app.WARNING: The class passed to the logging system does not have a
> handler

And the message is not entered in the log, tell me how to fix it?